# Rearrange one array using some rules in PHP

Tags: php

I want to rearrange one array such this:
$job1= array("d1"=>a, "d2"=>b, "d3"=>c, "d4"=>d, "d5"=>e, "d6"=>f, "d7"=>g, "d8"=>h, "d9"=>i, "d10"=>j);
into another array named $job2 using some rules.

d1, d2, d3,...,d10 are some days. a, b, c,...,j are some name of people.
in first array i want to show in each day one people go to the job1.

Rules:
In the new array i want to put in each day same people but going to job2 considering some rules.

1) In each day can't go one people to both jobs ($job1 and $job2). For example in d1 from $job2 can't go again "a" beacause in $job1 a goes in "d1".

2) If in d2 from $job1 go people "b", to $job2 people "b" can't go in d1 and d3.

Finally i want to change the order of how 10 people go to the job 2 considering they have yet one job.

Comment: i haven't tried anything. Did u understand what i want to make?

Comment: Can you provide us  any code ? :)

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can a,b,…,j people be the same, or are they supposed to be distinct ?

Comment: a,b,..,j are distinct people.

Comment: Then Mark Baker's answer is good, isn't it ?

Comment: i only want to rearrange same 10 people for another job considering some rules. Rules 1 and 2 prevent one people to go to the both jobs in same day and one people can't working  two days in row.

Comment: If that's really what you want to do, Mark Baker's solution is working. If not, please explain what you really want.

Comment: No Mark Baker's solution is not working like i want

Comment: Then I don't understand. Please give an example of job1 array, and a correct job2 array.

Comment: the new array i want to be like this $job2= array("d1"=>c, "d2"=>d, "d3"=>a, "d4"=>b, "d5"=g, "d6"=>h, "d7"=>e, "d8"=>f, "d9"=>k, "d10"=>l, "d11"=>i, "d12"=>j); I modified the the $job1 adding 2 more days (d11, d12) and 2 more people (k, l).

Comment: For the job1 in day1 go people "a", in day2 go people "b", ... , in day 12 go people "l". I want for the job2 in all 12 days to review again job1's days saying like that in your mind: in day1 from job1 go "a". So in day1 from job2 "a" can't go. In day2 form job1 go "b". So in day1 from job2 "b" can't go beacause was in day2 from job1 and can't working two days in row. In day3 from job1 go "c". So in day1 from job2 "c" can go because "c" does not go in day1 and day2 from job1. Thinking like that if "c" go in day1 from job2 he can go in day3 from job1.

Comment: Did u understand what i want to say? I review each day from job1 and who is working and considering 2 rules i put same people to the job2 switching the order. For example: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)=>(3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6, 11, 12, 9, 10).

Comment: Niols did u undestand what i'm taking about?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand, but perhaps something like:

```
$job1= array("d1"=>'a', "d2"=>'b', "d3"=>'c', "d4"=>'d', "d5"=>'e', "d6"=>'f', "d7"=>'g', "d8"=>'h', "d9"=>'i', "d10"=>'j');

$values = $job1;
array_unshift($values, array_pop($values));
array_unshift($values, array_pop($values));
$job2 = array_combine(array_keys($job1), $values);
var_dump($job2);
```

Comment: You should maybe unshift and pop twice, because of rule 2. If I understand correctly, rules 1 and 2 prevent you from working the same day, or two days in a row.

Comment: @Niols - you're probably right, I'm still trying to figure out the question

Comment: Yea Mark. Rules 1 and 2 prevent one people to go to the both jobs in same day and not working two days in row.

Comment: I think 3 array shifts would be better still, 2 shifts gives a 5 day cycle before somebody does the same job a second time; whereas 3 shifts covers the full range

Comment: For the job1 in day1 go people "a", in day2 go people "b", ... , in day 12 go people "l". I want for the job2 in all 12 days to review again job1's days saying like that in your mind: in day1 from job1 go "a". So in day1 from job2 "a" can't go. In day2 form job1 go "b". So in day1 from job2 "b" can't go beacause was in day2 from job1 and can't working two days in row. In day3 from job1 go "c". So in day1 from job2 "c" can go because "c" does not go in day1 and day2 from job1. Thinking like that if "c" go in day1 from job2 he can go in day3 from job1.

Comment: Did u understand what i want to say? I review each day from job1 and who is working and considering 2 rules i put same people to the job2 switching the order. For example: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)=>(3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 8, 5, 6, 11, 12, 9, 10).

Comment: Clearly I don't understand what you want to say: I thought this suggestion fulfilled both of the rules that you'd posted, but obviously you have some other rule that you don't seem to be explaining very well, so I'm bowing out of any further discussion on the matter